# TypeORM create constraint based on enum column and FK column?

Tags: postgresql, typeorm

I have the following table:

[image]

I must set a rule in that entity, so you can't have the same `home_account_user_id` and same `account_status` twice for example:

```
id | home_account_user_id | account_status
0  | 1                    | AWAY
0  | 1                    | AWAY
```

Should be:

```
id | home_account_user_id | account_status
0  | 1                    | AWAY
0  | 1                    | CLOSED
```

Is there a way to define it this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `UNIQUE` constraint/index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX udx_name ON tab_name(home_account_user_id, account_status);
```

Comment: So basically `@Unique(['home_account_user_id', 'account_status'])` ?

Comment: @BenBeri Yes, you could define it via ORM